# how to truncate the staging table?

Tags: google-bigquery

To keep the uniqueness of a column, my several clients stream data into a staging table in BQ(retry 2 times if not presence in main table with 10 mins interval), and using another cron job to MERGE staging table to a column partitioned table every several mins.

I need to truncate staging table if it's merged into main table, but it seems my clients are streaming data into all the time. Is there any recommendation here?

Answer (score 0):

**ALERT: Do not truncate** a table that is receiving streaming results.

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#streaming:

> Deleting and/or recreating a table may create a period of time where streaming inserts are effectively delivered to the old table and will not be present in the newly created table.
>
> Truncating a table's data (e.g. via a query job that uses writeDisposition of WRITE_TRUNCATE) may similarly cause subsequent inserts during the consistency period to be dropped.

For alternative best practices when streaming into BigQuery, see:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

In this case - why not have your several clients write to Pub/Sub instead? Then you can use Dataflow to move this data into permanent tables.

Bonus: Pub/sub + Dataflow + BigQuery can guarantee "Exactly Once" delivery.

Comment: Because of locking UPSERT semantic, I need to put data into a staging table, and automatically merge the staging table to main table by MERGE. I hope to run MERGE and TRUNCATE transactionally so I don't need to design staging table switch mechanism. is it possible?

Comment: typo locking -> lacking

Comment: BigQuery is append-only by design and is non-transactional, so what you are trying to do doesn't sound like the right approach for BigQuery. Have you considered @FelipeHoffa's suggestion of using Pub/Sub + Dataflow and Bigquery only as permanent destination?